# ffmpeg remove parts without motion and cut the video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, motion-detection

I am an Artist and I do very long drawing timelapses. I want to collapse my timelapses and cut everywhere where I don't move.

I want to shrink a 5 hour video to a few minutes video without speeding up the video.

I tried using this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.003),setpts=N/(25*TB)" output.mp4
```

I see the file size shrinking down to only few mb wich is good but the video duration is still the same.

I also tried this command

```
ffmpeg -i "2021-07-29 13-16-32.flv" -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB magic.mp4
```

Thank you for your help !